# hspan zorder not honored in Seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, data-visualization, boxplot

My axhspan regions are plotting over the top of of my boxplot, despite explicit zorder arguments to contrary.

My understanding (and past history) with zorder in matplotlib is smaller numbers should result in a background position and larger numbers should plot toward the "front". However I don't have alot of experience with Seaborn. When I check the seaborn and matplotlib documentation, it seems ok, but the plot says otherwise:

[image]

my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,5))
ax = sns.boxplot(x='ID_new',y='A',data=in_df,zorder=10)
plt.axhspan(5,15,zorder=1)
plt.show()
```

Do I need to be calling the axes differently, perhaps?

Cheers

Comment: Would `zorder=-1` work?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: just tested and it works.

Comment: Yes. plt.axhspan(5,15,zorder=-1) produced exacly what I was hoping to see.  Thank-you.  If you want to move your comment to a reply, I'll mark as 'answered'.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Change the `zorder` to `-1` as

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,5))
ax = sns.boxplot(x='ID_new',y='A',data=in_df,zorder=10)
plt.axhspan(5,15,zorder=-1)
plt.show()
```